# get json data in controller action in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-2, serialization

I have asp.net mvc application. i want to configure the object in jquery and want to pass it to the the action of controller . where as in my script i am using this for configure data for the ajax call:

```
var arr=new Array();

arr.Push(0)=1;
arr.Push(1)=2;
arr.Push(2)=3;

var  peform = {
                 EmpId: eId,
                 DepatrmentId:deptId,
                 EmpAddress:strAddress,
                 EmpBirthDate:bDate,
                 EmpAccountsId:arr
              };
```

I am able to get the values in param here but.
when I am trying this:

```
if(peform!=null)
            { 
                 var json = $.toJSON(peform);

                 $.ajax({
                 url: '/Load/SaveData',
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 data: json,
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 success: function (data) {

                }
        });
   }
```

it does not calls to action in controller. i think here :

```
 var json = $.toJSON(peform);
```

is not working as expect. is it need to add any js file to reference ? or mistake in syntax?
Or please suggest me any other remedy.

Comment: Can you put an alert(json); after that line and see what it outputs? Does it look correct? Have you included jquery?

Comment: What is your controller action defined as? Could you post the method signature? Thanks!

Comment: i tried alert before and after of the line , but i getting the alert which put before. but after is not executing. so i concluded that line is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(peform);
```